# Libgdx - Image Seems Stretched

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I create a game using libgdx for resolution 720x1280 (portrait).
I use image which the resolution is 720x1280, but I don't know why my image seems stretched. I think my image should appear normal with same resolution as screen.
Anybody know how to fix this?

Here is a piece of my code :

```
//set camera
camera = new OrthographicCamera(720, 1280);
camera.setToOrtho(true, 720, 1280);

//set sprite batch
batch = new SpriteBatch();
batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
```

Comment: Are you testing this on an Android device? Are you sure that your device uses that same resolution? Generally, you should update your viewport on every resize()... Basically, you just have to add something to your resize() method. And have a look at the `Viewport` class and wiki for more help on how to use the different Viewport types. https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Viewports

Comment: Yes, I test in on Desktop and tablet, in both of them, image seems stretched. I don't resize anything in my game, so I am confused why my image seems stretched.

Comment: Well the thing is if your devices actually really show that resolution? If not, your 720x1280 image will be stretched to whatever size and resolution your device display has... (if not running in immersive mode, think about the bar with the home buttons, which will take some of the resolution and is not part of your viewport)